# reserve indented format using HTML in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

without using any templating engine I often write something like this

```
success(data) {
  var html = '';
  if (data) {
    $.each(data.result, function() {
      html += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">'
      html += '<span class="icon-bar"></span>'
      html += '<span class="icon-bar"></span>'
      html += '<span class="icon-bar"></span>'
      html += '</button>'
    });
    $('something').append(html);

  }
}
```

if the html I want is massive it's hard to read, any way to keep the indentation in my case above?

Comment: Just add white space after the += as needed?

Comment: I have the save issue with you

Comment: I agree with @nnnnnn. Whenever I dynamically build html, I often append "\n" and "\t" to front of my strings, which seems to work nicely when rendered. It's a hell of an eyesore on the backend though.

Comment: are you "reading" the source in a dev tool? Chrome for example formats the html by default, thus negating the need to manually indent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **backticks** to define multi-line strings:

```
var buttonTemplate = `<button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>`;

if (data) {
  $.each(data.result, function() {
    $(buttonTemplate).appendTo('#something');
  });
}
```

Here is the working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/ua4chpkq/).

**Note** that it is a part of ECMAScript 6 standard and can be not working in some browsers:
[ES6 Template Strings compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-template_strings)

Answer (score 1):

You can create and store template in an array which is easirer to handle.Also you can store multiple template and use it acordingly

```
Templates = {};
Templates.temp = [
    `<button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>`
].join("\n");

if (data) {
  $.each(data.result, function() {
   $('#something').append($(Templates.temp));  // into jQuery object
  });
}
```

**NOTE**: " "  in join("\n") which is different from single quotes join('\n')

Answer (score 0):

In your html in save your template in a script tag with type of `text/template`(Any type ,which type not equals to `text/javascript`,will be ignored by the browser).

```
<script type="text/template" id="btnTpl">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</script>
```

And then you can use it in your javascript code:

```
var buttonTpl = $('#btnTpl').html();
if (data) {
  $.each(data.result, function() {
    $(buttonTpl).appendTo('#something');
  });
}
```